# are user defined classes mutable

Tags: python, class, immutability, mutable

Say I want to create a class for `car`, `tractor` and `boat`. All these classes have an instance of `engine` and I want to keep track of all the engines in a single list. If I understand correctly if the motor object is mutable i can store it as an attribute of `car` and also the same instance in a list.

I cant track down any solid info on whether user defined classes are mutable and if there is a choice to choose when you define them, can anybody shed some light?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056288/341459

Comment: If you have 2 cars, each with the same make and model of engine, do you want them to reference the same `engine` object, or different (yet equivalent) `engine` objects?

Comment: @Jonathan: You are supposed to select answers on your questions. You almost never do that.

Comment: Well spotted, and thanks for pointing it out, there are certainly a few I haven't found an answer I find fully answers the question but equally there are some I should mark as answered, Ill remedie that

Answer (score 41, accepted):

User classes are considered mutable. Python doesn't have (absolutely) private attributes, so you can always change a class by reaching into the internals.

For using your class as a key in a  `dict` or storing them in a `set`, you can define a [`.__hash__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and a [`.__eq__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), making a promise that your class is immutable. You generally design your class API to not mutate the internal state after creation in such cases.

For example, if your engines are uniquely defined by their id, you can use that as the basis of your hash:

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.id == other.id
        return NotImplemented
```

Now you can use instances of class Engine in sets:

```
>>> eng1 = Engine(1)
>>> eng2 = Engine(2)
>>> eng1 == eng2
False
>>> eng1 == eng1
True
>>> eng1 == Engine(1)
True
>>> engines = set([eng1, eng2])
>>> engines
set([<__main__.Engine object at 0x105ebef10>, <__main__.Engine object at 0x105ebef90>])
>>> engines.add(Engine(1))
>>> engines
set([<__main__.Engine object at 0x105ebef10>, <__main__.Engine object at 0x105ebef90>])
```

In the above sample I add another `Engine(1)` instance to the set, but it is recognized as already present and the set didn't change.

Note that as far as lists are concerned, the `.__eq__()` implementation is the important one; lists don't care if an object is mutable or not, but with the `.__eq__()` method in place you can test if a given engine is already in a list:

```
>>> Engine(1) in [eng1, eng2]
True
```

Comment: In sets, as keys for dicts, and anything else that requires a value be hashable.  Just be careful, as now even though the value you are hashing is mutable, interfaces using hash generally assume that the data for the hash is immutable for a given object or value.  Also, using `id` can be confusing since it is a reserved keyword in Python.

Comment: I think that it is worth pointing out that user defined classes have `__hash__` already implemented (for CPython, `__hash__` defaults to `id(self)`, so they *can* be used as dictionary keys... but then you have to use the same class every time you want to get an item from the dictionary.

Comment: But you didn't make sure there won't be two instances with the same ID.

Comment: @slallum: Nope, I didn't. Note that the OP didn't (explicitly) ask for that either. Also, you don't necessarily *need* to prevent multiple instances with the same id, the code *treats* them as the same.

Answer (score 1):

All objects (with the exception of a few in the standard library, some that implement special access mechanisms using things like descriptors and decorators, or some implemented in C) are mutable.  This includes instances of user defined classes, classes themselves, and even the type objects that define the classes.  You can even mutate a class object at runtime and have the modifications manifest in instances of the class created before the modification.  By and large, things are only immutable by convention in Python if you dig deep enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing mutability with how python keeps references -- Consider:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

t = (1,2,Foo())  # t is a tuple, :. t is immutable
b = a[2]  # b is an instance of Foo
b.foo = "Hello"  # b is mutable.  (I just changed it)
print (hash(b))  # b is hashable -- although the default hash isn't very useful
d = {b : 3}      # since b is hashable, it can be used as a key in a dictionary (or set).
c = t            # even though t is immutable, we can create multiple references to it.
a = [t]          # here we add another reference to t in a list.
```

Now to your question about getting/storing a list of engines globally -- There are a few different ways to do this, here's one:

```
class Engine(object):
     def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model

class EngineFactory(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self._engines = kwargs

    def all_engines(self):
        return self._engines.values()

    def __call__(self,make, model):
    """ Return the same object every for each make,model combination requested """
       if (make,model) in _engines:
           return self._engines[(make,model)]
       else:
           a = self._engines[(make,model)] = Engine(make,model)
           return a   

 engine_factory = EngineFactory()

 engine1 = engine_factory('cool_engine',1.0)           
 engine2 = engine_factory('cool_engine',1.0)
 engine1 is engine2 #True !!!  They're the same engine.  Changing engine1 changes engine2
```

The example above could be improved a little bit by having the `EngineFactory._engines` dict store `weakref.ref` objects instead of actually storing real references to the objects.  In that case, you'd check to make sure the reference is still alive (hasn't been garbage collected) before you return a new reference to the object.

Answer (score -3):

EDIT: This is conceptually wrong, [The immutable object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151080/the-immutable-object-in-python) can shed some light as to why.

```
class Engine():
    def __init__(self, sn):
        self.sn = sn

a = Engine(42)
b = a
print (a is b)
```

prints `True`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? You don't provide any explanation of why this code is relevant.

Comment: I thought that showed how the OP can "store it as an attribute of car and also the same instance in a list"

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- reading the question a few times, I don't think you were that far off.  I think your answer could use a little work explaining why it is relevant, but I don't think the OP really understands python references (and somehow has gotten that confused with mutability).