# Save a model instance with a non-existent field

Tags: python, django

I don't know if this is a bug or Django just allows it to happen. I have a Django model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I create an instance of it and assign a value to a non-existent field `address`:

```
author = Author()
author.name = 'abce'
author.address = 'defg'
author.save()
```

The instance is saved successfully and there is no error messages. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its normal, The address never actually gets saved and if you were to reference this object again, it wouldn't be there. Its just that Python qwerk that you are allowed to add fields to an object instance whenever you want

```
class A:
    pass
a = A()
a.foo = 1
```

<sub>Whether or not you should is a different matter...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In Python, user-defined types are generally `mutable`, which means they can be altered, and adding an `attribute` to a user-defined `object` is just like adding a `key` to an ordinary `dictionary`. You can check this answer for more details [are user defined classes mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12076539/4575071)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Normal. Django will do update only for the field you defined

From django code

> ```
>     for field in self._meta.concrete_fields:
>         if field.attname in non_loaded_fields:
>             # This field wasn't refreshed - skip ahead.
>             continue
>         setattr(self, field.attname, getattr(db_instance, field.attname))
> ```

You can see fields by

```
Author()._meta.concrete_fields
```

But you cannot do this like

```
Author(name="name", address="sss")
```

It will raise invalid argument.