# Does python list assignments update dynamically as pointers?

Tags: python, arrays

```
    %definition of a function

def array_left_rotation(a, n, k):
        b = a
        for i in range (n):
            a[(i-k)%n] = b[i]
        return a;        


    n, k = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    a = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    answer = array_left_rotation(a, n, k);
    print ' '.join(map(str,answer))
```

I have observed that list b is also changing on iteration even though it is defined outside the 'for' loop. Can someone tell me, is my assumption correct. if so please suggest the possible solution ?

Comment: Try `b = a[:]` and see if that solves it

Comment: `b = list(a)`
Or 
`import copy`
`new_list = copy.copy(old_list)`

Comment: You might be facing this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337788/variable-changes-if-i-change-a-different-variable/45337891#45337891